# Docker mysql connection fail with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

So I’m having troubles getting my Laravel app to connect to my MySQL container. With the following docker-compose I get the error:

> Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)

```
database:
  image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
     environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=root"
      - "MYSQL_PASS=secret"
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"
```

If I change my image to mysql I get the error:

> The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations)
>
> The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

My laravel .env looks like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I tried DB_HOST=database as well.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

OS: OSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have some old data in `dbdata` folder and they are causing a problem. If you don't need old DB, then just delete the content of this folder and start mysql container from the scratch. Another problem is a port. You are publishing MySQL on the port 33061, so Laravel should be configured with `DB_PORT=33061`.